# Edit XML Attribute which is selected based on another Attribute grouped with it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

New to XML, and I can't figure out how to alter an XML attribute where I select based on another XML attribute connected to it, so for example by XML file is structured as so:

```
<userinfo>
    <id username="tommy" password="supersecret" email="email@gmail.com" question="Favourite colour" answer="blue"></id>
    <id username="bobby" password="password123" email="derp@gmail.com" question="Pet name" answer="sally"></id>
    <id username="scotty" password="encrypted" email="herp@gmail.com" question="Favourite colour"  answer="blue"></id>
</userinfo>
```

I need to alter the password value based on a username. So for example, I have username "tommy", and I want to change tommy's password to a variable I have.

I tried the following, but appears to just do nothing, no errors just nothing:

```
protected void changePassword(string username, string password)
{
//xmlFile is the XDocument xml file path
    var query = from c in xmlFile.Descendants("id")
                .Where(id => (string)id.Attribute("username") == username)
                select c;

    foreach (XElement id in query)
    {
        id.Attribute("password").Value = password;
    }

    xmlFile.Save(@"xml\filepath\doc.xml");
}
```

This is based on what I've seen, though I've not seen how to do it using "where" so the "var query"... bit is what makes sense to work in my mind.

This is being used in asp.net and is called from a button:

```
    protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var change = Log.GetUserInfoForgot(username, txtNewPassword.Text); 
    }
```

Here I'll sound like a noob, but It won't let me just call the method, and I assign it to a var, even though it doesn't return anything. This is probably also causing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am 4 reputation short of being able to comment and ask for clarification, so I'm submitting this as an answer.

Your change password method works.  What I can't tell from your question is the correlation between the `Log.GetUserInfoForgot(...)` method call and the `changePassword` call. Where in GetUserInfoForgot is changePassword being called?

Comment: ....I'm bad, very bad. Yeah I put the wrong method name in the button, no wonder it wouldn't let me have it unless I set it to a variable. So yeah, my code does work, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered forgoing the LINQ query?

```
foreach(var el in xmlDoc.Descendents("id").Where(x => x.Attribute("username").Value == name)
{
    el.Attribute("Password").Value = password;
}
```

Comment: This throws a null reference error on the line within the foreach, though the passed variable is there.

Comment: The only way I can see that happening is if the xmlDoc variable is not in scope from the changePassword function.  If you think it should be in scope, try setting a stop point at that line and hover over the variable name when VS pauses debugging there.  You can see the contents of the variable.  If it says null, try passing that along with your username and password strings.